Variable not being alerted after useContext in React.js
I set the variable to the value in a parent function, then pass it as context to children, and then I set the UseEffect to alert it every time the variable changes, but it only alerts once when my App is restarted. I have 2 components to which I pass the same context, and one of them works fine, and another doesn't.
Here is my Context and variables:
interface WidgetContextType {
    accept: boolean;
    sortType: string;
}

const AcceptContext = React.createContext<WidgetContextType>({ accept: false, sortType: '' });

const [showTodo, setShowTodo] = useState(false);
const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('');

<Modal show={showSort} onHide={() => setShowSort(false)}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Sort Applications</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>How would you like to sort your Applications?</Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseNoSort}>No sorting</Button>
                                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCloseNameSort}>By name</Button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                        </Modal>

In the end I wrap children into Contgext:
<AcceptContext.Provider value={{ accept: accept, sortType: sortType }}>{children}</AcceptContext.Provider>

And here is the end of my file:
export const useAcceptContext = (): WidgetContextType => {
    return useContext(AcceptContext);
};

When I call it in my Todo file - it works fine, and when in Favorite application file - it doesn't.
Here is how I call it:
const s = useAcceptContext();
    const sortType = s.sortType;

    // Use useEffect to re-render FavoriteApps whenever sortType changes
    useEffect(() => {
        alert(`sortType changed: ${sortType}`);
    }, [sortType]);

    const sortedApps = useMemo(() => {
    // Sort logic based on sortType
        return [...apps].sort((a, b) => {
            if (sortType === 'name') {
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); // Sort alphabetically by name
            }
            return 0; // Default: no sorting
        });
    }, [apps, sortType]);



Can you verify if your other component that doesn't get alerted when context changes is wrapped in that context provider? You can add a console.log to check wether you're getting the context values or not.

@WaqasKhan I checked, and the todo widget gets the value, but the FavoriteApps doesn't. It console.logs only the empty string and does not change the value when I press on another button

Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example please? Although you've shared a good bit of code, there's not enough here to see what may be the cause.

You know assigning a variable doesn't trigger a re-render. If you want to have side effects, you should add states in the context. For example, for sortType, create a state [sortType, setSortType] = useState(), add both sortType and setSortType to the context, and use s.setSortType to change the value.
